# Will second OS harm my recovery partition?

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, multi-boot, recovery-partition

I've bought Asus N56VZ recently but the pre-installed Windows 8 didn't meet my expectations so I've decided to install higher version of Windows 8 on my HDD's second partition. I'm wondering about what will happen to my recovery partition when I install that second OS?

As a summary if I install second OS can I still reach the recovery partition with <kbd>F9</kbd> (pre assumed key)?

Update: I have one more partition on my drive. I will not delete my recovery partition. I will install the second OS on my second partition which is empty. İ will not wipe anything.

Update 2: Actually I have 4 partitions on my drive. One of them for OS, one of them for storage, one for recovery and one for restore (what their names are). I'm planning to install second OS on Storage partition.

Comment: Depends on how you install the second OS, and/or if you remove the recovery partition while doing it. Perhaps narrow down your question to cover exactly what your plan is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing will happen to the recovery partition unless you wipe it. The F9 key behavior at boot time should be due to the BIOS, not a bootloader in the recovery partition.

Comment: As you said when i install new OS F9 key continues to work like before?

Comment: I don't have any Asus machines, but from other brands, the hotkey-into-recovery-partition is a feature of the BIOS, so it should work as before. Like @Mayank Agarwal says, running recovery will wipe everything else, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 partitions, one for the OS and one for Recovery, that could mean several things. There are a few issues you might run into given your setup:

1) Recovery Partition may be too small to have an active OS on it

2) Recovery partition may be formatted improperly, meaning you would have to wipe it before loading Windows on it

3) If you do reformat your recovery partition to install Windows, you will no longer be able to boot to it, although the option may still be present in your BIOS.

If you are not planning on using the pre-installed Windows 8 any longer, I would recommend formatting that partition (not drive!) and installing your new OS on that. This way, you will be able to utilize your recovery partition and have your new version of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will happen, go ahead, the only thing is that when u factory reset your Laptop, all of your current OS, files, folders settings & secondary OS gets wiped down...and the laptop resets to the stage as if u have just unboxed it right now !